# How to assign the "table name" of a query in the powerpivot datamodel

Tags: excel, vba, powerpivot

I'm using PowerPivot, and I'm creating a table in the datamodel using the next code:

```
Set ObjConn = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2( _
    Name:= "SomeConnName", _
    Description:="DescSomeConn", _
    ConnectionString:="OLEDB;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=XXXX;User ID=YYYY;Password=ZZZ;Persist Security Info=true", _
    CommandText:="SELECT * FROM mytable", _
    lCmdtype:=xlCmdSql, _
    CreateModelConnection:=True, _
    ImportRelationships:=False)
```

It works well, except it always create the table named "Query".
I already searched in Microsoft Documentation and googled this way too much and I can't directly find where or how to set the table/query name.... or how to rename it after it was created.
Help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to @QHarr guide, I changed my approach to this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="QueryXY09", Formula:= _
    "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & " Source = OleDb.DataSource(""provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;data source=MyDWHConn;"", [Query=""SELECT * FROM mytable""])" _
    & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    
ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Add2 _
    "Query - QueryXY09", "Connection to the 'QueryXY09' query in the workbook.", _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=QueryXY09;Extended Properties=", _
    """QueryXY09""", 6, True, False
```

Which makes the goal, now I can set the name of the connection.
But this represents two problems. First data extraction is clearly slower, it seems it is using .net libraries, also, it looks like a double step.
Second, now I don't have a place to store the password, neither connection accept the user id/password for this approach. This last is the most worrisome, since the purpose of this is, of course, the automation of the extraction of data. However, I notice that, when I moved the file to a testing server, it prompted me for the user/password once, then I closed everything, open again and there was no prompt. So, where was the password saved?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. First it seems you can't get to a sheet directly from the workbook object, you have to use ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheet") to run. Then even after that, the listobjects belonging to that "mysheet" is empty. The thing is in powerpivot the query or table is sort of outside any sheet. It is not like a pivot table.

Comment: If I go to Power Pivot Manage, and try to macro a manual rename of the table, I get an empty macro. Like if those objects are out of scope of the regular excel model.

Comment: Sorry I don’t know how I missed out the . after thisworkbook and then worksheets(“sheetname”)

Comment: I've just found my object here: ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelTables(1).Name there is where the Power pivot queries are. But yet it seems I can't programmatically rename it. If I try `ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelTables(1).Name = "newname"`, I get the **Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment** error

Comment: It's a table in the model! The name property apparently is read-only.

Comment: Yes, the property seems readonly, though, it is not stated so in the VBA documentation. The workbook with the powerpivot inside is generated on the fly with vba.

Comment: you can see it is readonly in the object model via VBE. I have to wonder if it is named when setting up the connection. Unsure if I can run myself to have a play. Will need to have a think.

Comment: Yeah... the table name has to be changed in the query.

Comment: which is in ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="SomeName" In the connection.Add2 it references via Extended Properties=" _
        , """SomeName"""

Comment: Don't have access to sql at present but this was adding via in sheet table https://pastebin.com/Dpahma3C

Comment: Sorry I just don't get the "formula" pararameter, looks like that is for an excel file as datasource. It seems that's for Power Query.... and what I'm using is a Power Pivot.

Comment: Yes because, as I mentioned, I don't currently have access to SQL source. Power pivot makes its connection to data sources using power query. https://powerpivotpro.com/what-is-power-pivot/ => _"Everything in Power Pivot revolves around the Data Model.  You connect to your data through Power Query, which can be used to help with data discovery, shaping, and import. Data is then loaded and enhanced (via smart formulas and table relationships) to form data models"_

Comment: Right now, with the code provided in the original post, I'm creating a connection to an Oracle DB, and the corresponding data in Powerpivot **without** any query. I don't have a single query in the Queries&Connection panel. What I do have, is a double connection, one named `ThisWorkbookDataModel` and other `MyProdDBConn` which contains the OLEDB connection. If what you say works, I would need the right syntax for the "Formula" using an OLEDB connection, I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I’ll have a look into it tomorrow hopefully. See if I can follow similar process to you.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr, it seems I got it working but.... it raised a couple of question, please see my edit. Looks like you're the only expert on this matter, thanks for your time.

Comment: This sounds like it will take some time to investigate. Usually, with other work I have done I use a trusted property in the connection which doesn’t require any manual input of username + password. Will see what I can do tomorrow. As for slower - possibly. Should have been relatively quick as doesn’t actually load to sheet. Is it the set-up which is slower or refresh? There are more experienced people of SO but they may have missed this. Let me have a think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221051/discussion-between-qharr-and-cesar-vega).